# Any volume control applet for openbox?

Tags: sound, openbox

Folks,

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 minimal + openbox. It is a development box. Audio is based on alsa.

I love the lightweightness of openbox. I don't even use tint2 as I feel it doesn't add much value. For the system tray, I just use a lightweight app called docker.

The only thing I am missing is a lightweight volume control applet that can go into the system tray.

I saw an application called volume icon that might fit the bill:

http://softwarebakery.com/maato/volumeicon.html

However, am I not sure if it is being actively developed.

I am wondering if you have a suggest for a volume control applet that is lightweight and is developed somewhat actively.

If needed, I can stoop down to using tint2.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT MAY 16 2015**

Since upgrading to 15.04, gnome-control-center has been misbehaving and gnome-sound-applet disappeared, so I've decided to search for other alternatives, and found `volti`. Works pretty much the same, still being launched from my `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file

**Tools to install**

1. gnome-control-center
2. gnome-alsamixer
3. tint2 panel

**Option 1: gnome-alsamixer**

Gnome Alsamixer is a graphical front end for alsamixer ( the ncurses-based command line utility for sound control ). Install it via apt-get and add gnome-alsamixer.desktop to the tint2 panel. (see my tint2rc file bellow).

[image]

**Option 2: gnome-sound-applet**

If you have `gnome-control-center` installed, you may use the sound indicator/applet. Install the `gnome-control-center` and add a line `gnome-sound-applet &` to your `.config/openbox/autostart` file.

**Option 3: use razor-panel**

Razor panel has its own sound indicator and is part of razorqt desktop environment, but may be installed independently. Download it using `sudo apt-get install razor-panel` . To autostart it, add `razor-panel &` to your `.config/openbox/autostart` file.

**Option 4: Pulse Audio Volume Control**

The name describes what it is aptly enough. Simply, right click on the desktop , go to Debian -> Applications -> Sound -> pavucontrol.
[image]

**My .config/openbox/autostart file**

```
# set background
feh --bg-fill /home/xieerqi/.local/share/wallpapers/ben.jpg &

# start tint2 panel
tint2 &

# start razor-panel
# razor-panel &

# start gnome-sound-applet
gnome-sound-applet &
```

**My .config/tint2/tint2rc file**

```
# Tint2 config file
# Generated by tintwizard (http://code.google.com/p/tintwizard/)
# For information on manually configuring tint2 see http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Configure

# Background definitions
# ID 1
rounded = 7
border_width = 2
background_color = #000000 60
border_color = #FFFFFF 16

# ID 2
rounded = 5
border_width = 0
background_color = #FFFFFF 40
border_color = #FFFFFF 48

# ID 3
rounded = 5
border_width = 0
background_color = #FFFFFF 16
border_color = #FFFFFF 68

# Panel
panel_items = LTSBC
panel_monitor = all
panel_position = bottom center horizontal
panel_size = 85% 50
panel_margin = 0 0
panel_padding = 7 0 7
panel_dock = 0
wm_menu = 1
panel_layer = top
panel_background_id = 1

# Panel Autohide
autohide = 0
autohide_show_timeout = 0.3
autohide_hide_timeout = 2
autohide_height = 2
strut_policy = follow_size

# Taskbar
taskbar_mode = single_desktop
taskbar_padding = 2 3 2
taskbar_background_id = 0
taskbar_active_background_id = 0

# Tasks
urgent_nb_of_blink = 8
task_icon = 1
task_text = 0
task_centered = 1
task_maximum_size = 140 35
task_padding = 6 2
task_background_id = 3
task_active_background_id = 2
task_urgent_background_id = 2
task_iconified_background_id = 3
task_tooltip = 0

# Task Icons
task_icon_asb = 70 0 0
task_active_icon_asb = 100 0 0
task_urgent_icon_asb = 100 0 0
task_iconified_icon_asb = 70 0 0

# Fonts
task_font = sans 7
task_font_color = #FFFFFF 68
task_active_font_color = #FFFFFF 83
task_urgent_font_color = #FFFFFF 83
task_iconified_font_color = #FFFFFF 68
font_shadow = 0

# System Tray
systray = 1
systray_padding = 4 2 3
systray_sort = ascending
systray_background_id = 0
systray_icon_size = 35
systray_icon_asb = 70 0 0

# Clock
time1_format = %H:%M
time1_font = sans 8
time2_format = %A %d %B
time2_font = sans 6
clock_font_color = #FFFFFF 74
clock_padding = 1 0
clock_background_id = 0
clock_rclick_command = orage

# Tooltips
tooltip_padding = 2 2
tooltip_show_timeout = 0.7
tooltip_hide_timeout = 0.3
tooltip_background_id = 1
tooltip_font = sans 10
tooltip_font_color = #000000 80

# Mouse
mouse_middle = none
mouse_right = close
mouse_scroll_up = toggle
mouse_scroll_down = iconify

# Battery
battery = 1
battery_low_status = 10
battery_low_cmd = notify-send "battery low"
battery_hide = 98
bat1_font = sans 8
bat2_font = sans 6
battery_font_color = #FFFFFF 74
battery_padding = 1 0
battery_background_id = 0



# Launchers
#   
launcher_padding = 5 0 10
launcher_background_id = 9
launcher_icon_size = 45
launcher_item_app = /home/xieerqi/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop
# launcher_item_app = /some/where/anotherapplication.desktop
launcher_item_app =  /home/xieerqi/.config/autostart/gnome-terminal.desktop
launcher_item_app = /home/xieerqi/.config/tint2/backlight.desktop
# launcher_item_app = /home/xieerqi/.local/share/applications/backlight.desktop 
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/gnome-alsamixer.desktop
# End of config
```

**Note about config files**

You may want to reboot or at least do `sudo service lightdm restart` from TTY1 in order to enable changes done to the config files

**How the set up might look**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use pavucontrol as a icon on a status bar like i3status?

Comment: @LnxSlck I'm not familiar with i3status, so I can't say. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

PNMixer is another alternative, it's a fairly complete and configurable sound applet. It's been around for a while now, and it's well maintained.

There's an Ubuntu package here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pnmixer

For the latest version, please visit the GitHub page:
https://github.com/nicklan/pnmixer

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer of PNMixer.*

Comment: Just tried it and like it because because it provides a system-tray icon for changing volume but also for launching gnome-alsamixer.

Comment: `sudo apt install pnmixer`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the "volumeicon" package. It is a sytemtray icon, it is quite simple it does what must be done.

Comment: In Ubuntu the name of the actual package is _volumeicon-alsa_